I got a compiler issue when using emplace_back()
When I trying to use emplace_back for my vector, I got the compile issue by clang15, but got passed by clang16. Here is the code:
struct test
{
    size_t value;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<test> list{};

    size_t data = 5;

    list.emplace_back(data);

    return 0;
}

here is the link from godbolt: text
I just want to know if this is a compiler issue or this is not a good example in c++ language.

TL;DR of the dupe: this has been fixed in C++20.  pre that you have to have a constructor to use emplace.

Parenthesized initialization of aggregates is a C++20 feature, which is supported from Clang16.

But why code can work if I change the code to : list.emplace_back(Test{data});  without having a constructor.
